# OpenVR IPD distance between eyes needed for masking in shaders

Tags: unity, shaders, virtual-reality

I have a Unity scene with OpenVR and Single Pass Stereo Rendering.

I need to do a fullscreen 3D masking effect in VR, based on reconstructed worldspace position from depth. I'm doing it using Graphics.Blit and a fullscreen quad.

This is what it looks like:
[image]

The problem is once you have the reconstructed world pos, you can't just say "everything past `wpos.x==300` is black", because each eye will offset the mask and it appears like you're looking at it cross-eyed.

This is because the `wpos.x==300` method does not take into account the Interpupillary Distance (IPD) between the two vr "cameras" rendering the scene. According to the [unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/Manual/SinglePassStereoRendering.html) there's a `unity_StereoEyeIndex`, and I used that to offset the eye ray for each eye by an arbitrary amount in camera space.

I can eyeball this offset using a float, but my question is how do you calculate it exactly? **How do you make stereo masking shaders in VR?**

### [EDIT]

I haven't yet reverse-engineered the problem fully, and am still waiting for a full answer. But I have fixed it for now by avoiding `Graphics.Blit()` because it's too mysterious in VR, and instead used a sphere in the game world with a special material.

The shader I use is basically what @DMGregory did [in this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/131978/shader-reconstructing-position-from-depth-in-vr-through-projection-matrix) for his "Object in World" method. Note that you have to correct the depth sampling with this:

```
screenUV = UnityStereoTransformScreenSpaceTex(screenUV);
screenUV.y = 1.0f - screenUV.y;
```

Comment: I wrote an [earlier answer about reconstructing worldspace position within skewed frusta in VR](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/131978/shader-reconstructing-position-from-depth-in-vr-through-projection-matrix) - would that address your issue?

Comment: Oh hey DMGregory, I am using your answer actually. But I added my per-eye offset on top of it: `clip.x +=(unity_StereoEyeIndex * 2 - 1) * _EyeDistOffsetTemp;`. Also, I found that in your answer `var p = _camera.projectionMatrix;` is wrong right now (maybe a unity update broke it). Because the projection is slightly off and moving your head around you can see, especially in the distance, that the reconstructed world pos rotates slightly more than the regular geometry. Did you test your code recently?

Comment: Adding the per-eye offset might be the problem — the quad version already includes that offset natively via the camera's view & projection matrices. So if you're using that version you might be doubling up. (And if you're not using that version, try it — I trust its math more than I trust the blitting script) ;)

Comment: Hmmmm.... unless Unity is not truthfully populating `_WorldSpaceCameraPos` for each VR camera. In which case we should be able to dig the true values out of the translation component of the view matrix. Let me know if that looks like the issue, and I can update that answer to calculate this vector rather than trust the built-in one. Unfortunately my VR rig is on loan for an exhibit so I can't verify with real hardware right now.

Comment: I just tested exactly what you wrote in "Blit / Post Effect". And the projection is off, and the eyes aren't offsetted, like I said. I'm using version 1.2.1 of the OpenVR Plugin, Unity 5.5.0f3, Single Pass Stereo Rendering Method. If it works for you and not for me then there must be some black magic involved.

Comment: Good idea with the translation component of the view matrix. I'm'a try it.